# Why my SESSID_id (cookie) cloned with blank name

Tags: perl, session, cgi

i'm writing a simple auth methods for a simple application

```
sub Kernel::get_cookie
{
    my ($q, %vars) = @_;

    # Crea la sesion
    my $sid = $q->cookie($vars{'COOKIE_NAME'}) || undef;
    my $session = undef;

    if(!$sid) {
        $session = CGI::Session->new('id:md5', $q, {Directory=>$vars{'SESSION_DIR'}});
    } else {
        $session = CGI::Session->load($q);
    }

    # Genera la cookie
    my $cookie = $q->cookie(
        -name => $vars{'COOKIE_NAME'},
        -value => $session->id
    );

    # regresa la cookie
    return $cookie;
}

# ... in main code
print $q->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
```

the first time i get the cookie fine, but when i refresh the page o get the cookie twice
and the second have a blank name

```
'CGICOOKIE': '1a2c3s4d5d6...'
        '' : '1a2c3s4d5d6...'
```

i'm newbie in perl (few hours) and i need a simple login sistem but the examples i've found (all) are incomplete or inaccurate

Comment: Besides the cookie issue, you should probably not declare your session object (`$session`) lexically inside this subroutine. You can use it to store information about the user, like if he is logged in. You can also save other things like breadcrumbs (which sites did he visit) or results from expensive database queries in the session. Right now you are creating the object and throwing it away. You should return it together with `$cookie`.

Comment: Also, how do you call that sub `Kernel::get_cookie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from

```
$q->cookie(
    -name => $vars{'COOKIE_NAME'},
    -value => $session->id
);
```

returning a session id string the second time, not a `CGI::Cookie` object like the first time.

---

Your code goes through ridiculous contortions to get at the cookie. Let CGI::Session handle all that! Your whole code can be substituted with:

```
use CGI qw();
use CGI::Session qw();

my %vars = (
    COOKIE_NAME => 'CGICOOKIE',
    SESSION_DIR => '/tmp',
);
my $q = CGI->new;
CGI::Session->name($vars{COOKIE_NAME});
my $session = CGI::Session->new('id:md5', $q, {Directory=>$vars{'SESSION_DIR'}});

print $session->header(-type => 'text/plain');
# prints cookie header, too
print 'hi';
```

See [`header` in CGI::Session](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aSession#header-).